# Is it acceptable to repost someone else's deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Let's say someone wrote a good answer, and later deleted it for some reason. At a certain reputation level, we can see deleted answers, so we also have a technical ability to repost deleted answers.

In case I see a good answer that was deleted by the owner, and in case I have a reason to think they will not undelete it—can I copy the text of the answer and post it as a new answer? In case this is acceptable, should I also convert the reposted answer to a community wiki?

Comment: *At a certain reputation level, we can see deleted answers, so we also have a technical ability to repost deleted answers.* At that level, you also have the ability to vote to undelete them, which would be the way to go.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi A good point, although you can see deleted answers already at 10k, and casting undelete votes is something only trusted users (20k+) can do.

Comment: True, I forgot it was a two-step process. So there is indeed a window where reposting is all that you can do (barring flagging for undeletion).